# Trouble dynamically loading smoothdivscroll

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to load smoothdivscroll dynamically (so I can have many galleries on my site).

Static html works fine. As soon as I try to enable the plugin for dynamically loaded content, it does not work.

It seems to be a timing thing. Ive noticed that if the initialization of smoothdivscroll, ie.

```
$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({});
```

is not done as part of the page load then it does not work.

Have a look at this example I created: http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr4U/119/

When you set the load_delayed variable to true then the initialization is called after the page has loaded and smoothdivscroll breaks.

What am I doing wrong or is this a limitation of the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the limitation of the plugin. I am facing the same problem. 
The plugin uses window.load(), which is not invoked other than on page load.

[check the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr4U/1558/)

You need to manually invoke the

```
$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("recalculateScrollableArea");

$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
```

}